# Bootstrap Treeview links with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, treeview, href, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and Bootstrap Treeview.
I have enabled the node text as link:

```
  $('#treeview').treeview({data: data, enableLinks: true});
```

and in the href field of each node in the Json array I have the laravel route

```
 "{{ route('opciones.create') }}"
```

Here is where I create the tree (I encode this to Json format in another part of my code)

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {

     $element['text'] = $element['descripcion'];
     $element['href'] = "{{ route('opciones.create') }}";
     if ($element['padre'] == $parentId){
            $nodes = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($nodes) {
                $element['nodes'] = $nodes;
            }

            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

This is the function in the controller that I need to call which returns a view (a blade file)

```
  public function create()
    {    $opcionespadre = Opcion::where('tipo', '=', 'SUBMENU')->get();
         return view($this->path.'.create', compact('opcionespadre'));
    }
```

I am using this especific function just to test the tree nodes links, I have other functions in the controller where I need to send a parameter, but first I need to make the link goes somewhere.

When I click on the text of the node, it says that the page I am looking for doesn't exist. 
This is what appears in the browser bar:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{route('opciones.create')}}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Show us the code where did you put `"{{ route('opciones.create') }}"` and is it a blade file ?

Comment: it is a route to a controller function that returns a view.

Comment: I mean the code in the treeview where the herf is !! and is it a blade file

Comment: I updated the question with the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
$element['href'] = "{{ route('opciones.create') }}";
```

Do it like this :

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {

     $element['text'] = $element['descripcion'];
     $element['href'] = route('opciones.create');
     if ($element['padre'] == $parentId){
            $nodes = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($nodes) {
                $element['nodes'] = $nodes;
            }

            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```